# Why all fields appear as dimensions in data studio?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio, google-apps-script-api

I'm working on the ***npm Downloads Counter*** connecter using this Google Data Studio [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors#7).
In the getFields() function i created two dimensions( 'day' and 'packageName') and one metric(downloads).
But in Data Studio, all fields appear as dimensions, there is no metric.

**getFields() function**

```js
function getFields() {
  var fields = cc.getFields();
  var types = cc.FieldType;
  var aggregations = cc.AggregationType;

  fields
    .newDimension()
    .setId('packageName')
    .setName('Package')
    .setType(types.TEXT);

  fields
    .newDimension()
    .setId('day')
    .setName('Date')
    .setType(types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY);

  fields
    .newMetric()
    .setId('downloads')
    .setName('Downloads')
    .setType(types.NUMBER)
    .setAggregation(aggregations.SUM);

  return fields;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The snippet isn't complete as cc has not been declared. P.S. Stack Snippets should be used only for executable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Green" Number fields are currently the expected output (thus, in this case, the `Downloads` Number field displayed as a "Green" Dimension is the expected behaviour) and was part of the [31 Oct 2019 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9691261#oct-31-2019) to Google Data Studio, which "*[Improved data modeling in Data Sources](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6402048?ref_topic=7441655)"*.

"Blue" Metric fields would be values that are pre-aggregated, such as the Metrics in the Google Analytics Data Source or creating an [Aggregated](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9320174) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) in your respective Data Source such as `SUM(Downloads)` which would be displayed as a "Blue" Metric.

To elaborate on the update, adding a section from the release notes:

> You don't need to take any action. Charts and calculated fields used
> in your reports will work as before the upgrade. However, if you
> create or edit data sources from flexible schema (or tabular) data
> sets, such as Sheets or BigQuery, you may notice that number fields
> that previously appeared as metrics (blue fields) with an aggregation
> of None now appear as green dimensions with a new Default Aggregation
> of Sum. This change has no effect in existing charts, but makes it
> easier to use these fields in more flexible ways.

Source: [Announcing data modeling improvements (02 Nov 2019)](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/18307022)